# How to solve this layout design-error due to conflicting css?

Tags: css

The design of the page should look like this:

http://www.ski.kommune.no/Skoler/Finstad/

Another css-file is loaded in this page, bringing some unwanted attribute of the css-tags, which makes the design undesirable, e.g. the text in the blue field is moved.
    http://www.ski.kommune.no/Skoler/Finstad/Praktisk-informasjon/Test-av-bildegalleri/

Which css-tags are creating the design problem in the above example? I looked with Firebug, but I couldn't find. 
What is the best way to restore the design?

Comment: Please don't ask users to reverse-engineer external sites. Please post the relevant code as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from 5th item in your main horizontal menu.
The list item there has a `class="calendar"`.
according to browser developer tools that class is:

```
.skole .calendar, .skole .news-list {
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

the problem there is margin bottom.
  to solve the problem:
the best way is to separate the 2 classes and remove the margin-bottom from the calendar class.
a word of advice:
try learn how to use different browsers developer tools.
in my view the bests are chrome and firebug.
have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your reply and advice!
I added this fix into the css:
 ul#menu li.calendar
 
 {
 margin-bottom: auto !important;
 }